# Java: Not autosize in JTabbed pane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, autosize

i'm actually a simple beginner studying java. Well, i got some problems using JTabbedPane, i want 3 tabs, the first one shows table content (inside a jtable)

[image: Tab Table]

The second one allows to add new data in the table (it contains some just some jlabels and textfields) but when i go to "edit" Tab, it's autosize with  table tab.

[image: Tab Edit]

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for ur answer, fixed it using MigLayout :D

`jpane4.setLayout(new MigLayout("center"));`

`for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {`
`columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));`
`JLabel jlAdd = new JLabel(metaData.getColumnName(column));`
`JTextField tbAdd = new JTextField(10);`
`jpane4.add(jlAdd, "alignx trailing");`
`jpane4.add(tbAdd, "wrap");`
`textFields.add(tbAdd);`
`stringColab.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));`
`}`